# Dropping field in model after wrote all viwes

Tags: python, django

I have a model with some fields. I wrote some views "def" and forms. I need to drop one field and want to add fields to that model. if I do this, how bad it will affect my views and forms?

Comment: Are you aware of how migrations work in Django (I'm assuming you're either using a newer Django or South, since you specifically mentioned migrations in your comment below)?  Applying a migration will update your database (potentially including prompting you for what default value to use if you added a field that can't be null).  As far as your views/forms, that will depend somewhat on what they're doing; if they reference a deleted field, you'll need to remove that; if they specify which fields to include and that doesn't include your new field, you'll want to add it.

Comment: thank you! I understood.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do add fields to the model in the view. You can exclude fields in the form (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#selecting-the-fields-to-use) and add a new field to form (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#a-full-example).

Comment: Thanks for your response. And I'm sorry for not making my question clear. I want to add and delete fields in the model. Not in the view. If I add a field and migrate that, then will this affect my views and forms? will my database become inconsistent?

Comment: It's can affect. If you using this field in the view or form. Example:
`def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                _user = kwargs.pop('_user', False)
                super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
                if not _user.is_superuser:
                        del self.fields['created_by']
                        del self.fields['performer']
`